# django query with QuerySet objects

Tags: python, django

assuming this is my models

```
class Organizer(models.Model):
     # properties
class Event(models.Model):
     organizer = models.ForeignKey(Organizer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     # other properties
class Ticket(models.Model):
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     # other properties
class Register(models.Model):
     ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
```

I have a `Organizer` object `org_obj` and I want to get a list of all events that have more than 20 registers made for this `Organizer`

this is my code:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(organizer=org_obj)
event20 = []
    for e in events.iterator():
        tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event=e)
        tickets_sold = 0
        for t in tickets.iterator():
            tickets_sold += Register.objects.filter(ticket=t).count()
        if tickets_sold > 20:
            event20.append(e)
```

is there to improve this query not using loops?
In plain SQL this should be possible with `join` expressions and Subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just annotate your `Event`s with the number of `Register`s, and then filter on that, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

event20 = org_obj.event_set.annotate(
    nregister=Count('ticket__register')
).filter(nregister__gt=20)
```

This is a `QuerySet` that contains the `Event`s related to this `Organizer` with (strictly) more than 20 related `Register` objects. You can filter on `nregister__gte=20` to obtain the `Event`s with 20 or more (so 20 included) `Register`s.

Django will construct a query that looks similar to:

```
SELECT event.*,
       COUNT(register.id) AS nregister
FROM event
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket ON event.id = ticket.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN register ON ticket.id = register.ticket_id
WHERE event.organizer_id = org_obj_id
GROUP BY event.id
HAVING COUNT(register.id) > 20
```

With *`org_obj_id`* the primary key value of the `org_obj` object.